# How to use regex expression (using sed) in windows using cygwin without removing carriage return?

Tags: regex, svn, sed, diff, carriage-return

I am currently using Cygwin in Windows. If I use sed to search and replace, carriage returns are removed since files are left with the unix touch of not having \r at the end of the lines.

This is a problem when using subversion, for example, since a file seems to have been changed completely if its carriage return lines are removed.

How can I use a regex expression, such as the following without effecting all my lines.

```
sed -i -e "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g" `grep -rl SEARCH *`
```

Comment: Does running `unix2dos` on the file(s) after the search/replace correct the touch?

Comment: It did, but would that mean that you would have to traverse through all the set of files twice? grep SEARCH -> use sed (changes to REPLACE + leaves in line characters) -> grep REPLACE -> unix2dos?

Comment: Please see my answer below for a solution that allows both (and many more) actions per iteration of the "search" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does the job:

```
 sed -i -e "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g;s/$/\\r/" `grep -rl SEARCH *`
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your concern about doing more than the one `sed` operation in one pass, please consider the following:

```
$ grep -rl SEARCH * | while read MYFILE;
>   do sed -i -e "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g" $MYFILE; 
>   unix2dos $MYFILE;
> done
```

By piping the results of `grep` into `read` we create a variable with the filename that contains the search target.  After that you can do any number of operations on the same file in one cycle of the loop.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cygwin, but use the native GnuTools32 collection, which includes a sed.

[native Win32 ports of some gnu utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

I'm not sure, whether there is a Win64 port already, and whether this would be more useful for some.

If you install them, they're not part of the path. If you make them appear in the PATH, notice, that some of them will either not be visible, because they come later in the PATH as Windows with name clashing, or they will hide the Windows counterpart - which is important for `find`.

I would suggest to keep the windows programs first, to keep existing scripts working, but maybe rename the ones (find-> gnufind) to make them easily accessible.

Please note: I'm not sure, whether this **sed** respects windows newlines, but I think so - it makes much more sense. Please try it and report.

Beneath *sed*, you get *grep, find, wc, rev, tac*, and and many more. :)

Comment: The cygwin `sed` version is much more updated than GnuTools32.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this command has worked well:

```
 sed -i -e "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g;s/$/\r/" `grep -rl SEARCH *`
```